# Is there a way to access the root dictionary used by Jinja2 from within a template?

Tags: python, jinja2

Note: The lead-up to the question is a bit long, since I want to share the various ways of dealing with this issue, to help others struggling with it.

I'm trying to use Jinja2 in Python to format AWS SNS events (which are nested dictionaries). For example:

```
event = {
  "id": "c3a1d2c9-3364-e31b-2ef0-2c6d38933ca2",
  "detail-type": "CloudWatch Alarm State Change",
  "source": "aws.cloudwatch",
  "time": "2019-10-02T17:04:40Z",
  "detail": {
    "alarmName": "ServerCpuTooHigh",
    "configuration": {
...
```

and I can make a template that looks like

```
{{ source }} had a problem
```

and then use `template.render(event)` to produce "aws.cloudwatch had a problem".

Where I'm having difficulty is with data fields with hyphens (or any other character not allowed in a Python identifier). Trying to use `{{ detail-type }}`, for example, throws an exception.

There are only two ways I can think of to get around this:

First, I can sanitize all of the keys in the dictionary to remove offending characters (which is what I'm doing now, but it bears the slight risk of collision with other keys)

The second way is to use Jinja2's support for calling `get()` or bracket notation to reference fields in the dictionary (like `{{ event.get('detail-type') }}` or `{{ event['detail-type'] }}`) but this requires that I have the an identifier ('event' in the examples I just used) that maps to the root of my dictionary, and *that requires that my entire dictionary be passed within a containing **kwargs dictionary*, like `template.render(event=event)`. The problem with *that* is that this now requires that *all* of my field references now have this prefix (so every field reference like `{{ source }}` now has to be changed to `{{ event.source }}`. This is a pretty high syntactic cost just to be able to access fields with hyphens. I can only think of two ways to address this issue (and be able to refer to most fields directly while still gaining access to problem keys):

1. Move the problem keys in the root dictionary into a sub-dictionary (say, 'problemkeys' for illustrating the idea), so I could do something like `{{ source }} had a problem relating to {{ problemkeys.get['detail-type'] }}`.
2. If Jinja2 were to have some rarely-needed identifier (say, '_top') for getting to the **kwargs, then, when needed, we'd be able to use `{{ _top['detail-type'] }}`.

**So, the question is:** *Is* there an identifier we can use to access the top of the **kwargs we passed in to `render()`?

Edit: I think another reason for such a reference to the root dictionary would be to enable iterating over all of the root keys, like `{% for key,val in _top.items() %}`.

Answer (score 1):

To the `.render` method you could pass **both** the "root" dictionary and the event's fields:

```python3
template.render(event, event=event)
```

That way your template will have "fast access" to the event's fields:

```jinja2
{{ source }} had a problem
```

and access to the event object itself:

```
{{ event['detail-type'] }}
```

In case your `event` object will have the `event` field, the field could be accessed using "long" notation:

```
{{ event['event'] }}
```